# ASP.NET not parsing query strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

I'm working on a web application and instead of using Membership I use the FormsAuthentication directly.

The problem is when I do a Form post I'm able to get all of the fields but it is not parsing the query strings.

When I look in the debugger the query string is there in the URI but not in the QueryString array.

I'm trying to get the ReturnUrl from the query string so I can make the login page go to the correct spot.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to parse that `QueryString`; try just call in your login page:

```
if(Request.Params["ReturnUrl"] != null)
{
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName, createPersistentCookie);
}
```

Comment: The problem I'm having is the Query string is not showing up in the QueryString[] so the Request.Params["ReturnUrl"] will not work for me.

Comment: cant you just call FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage?